# How is the MUI DataGrid API meant to be used?

Tags: api, datagrid, documentation, legacy, mui-datatable

At the moment, the MUI documentation for the datagrid offers two options: 1) the legacy API and 2) the experimental API. This is already a bit misleading.
My understanding is, that the experimental API is basically what people should use right now. Furthermore, I'd assume that the logic might flip with the next release and not the experimental needs the explicit switch, but rather the legacy will need it.

What isn't clear to me is, which part is really different between experimental and legacy and which is not.

For example manipulating rows as suggested with the experimental API is explained to be done by holding a rows array as state and replacing it all-together. Imagining tens of thousands of rows, the component will have a hard time figuring out which rows actually have changed... In contrast to this, the legacy api description suggests to use the apiRef to perform an incremental row update. Potentially this could be much more efficient, is this one still safe to use in the experimental api?

Other than that I am having a hard time wiring this table up to a backend. In general this is working very nicely, but the details are really hard to get right.
For example I tried very hard to use our database keys in as row ids. This worked fine up to the point when trying to create new rows. I implenmented a row-factory that generates an empty row with id -1. Now this row can be edited and after that committed to the persistence api. After that, the api ofcourse returns the new actual database-id. After hours of trying I have not been able to update the rowid and the row-content in the same frame without the table mixing up old and new content. Any solution here shouldn't be too hacky as it is a very central and basic operation. So I decided to generate artifical frontend-rowids and keep the db-id as row-data.

I tryed to learn more about the best practices, concepts and ideas of the legacy and experimental api by reading the documentation. I also expected to find information about a stable api. All I found was a hint, that experimental can be considered stable :D